# Best data structure in python for non-constant amount of elements

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, data-structures

I have a random distribution of points in 2D space, and a 2D grid. I want to log in which cell in the grid each point is. For example, `grid[5,6]` will return `[2, 53, 70, 153]`, which are the indices of the points located inside the cell `[5,6]`.

It is crucial that the data will be saved in the grid by indexing the circles, and not the other way round, since later I'm going to use this grid structure to compare close points to each other, and the grid will allow me to see which points are close.

I'm working in python, and the points are stored as a 2D `numpy array`.

What is the best way to implement the grid data structure? Notice that the number of circles in each cell is non constant and unknown.

Thanks a lot!

P.S. As a non-native speaker, I think the title for my question is cumbersome and unclear, but I couldn't find a better way to summarize my question. If anyone has a better way to express that, please feel free to fix my title. Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you're asking about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning, in which case consider a k-d tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) or other spatial partitioning structure.

Comment: I tried to read, and yes: this is basically what I want, to split space into sections. But it's still unclear to me how should I implement that in python, nor after it is implemented how to use it in my specific use case (for example, getting all of the points in a specific section)